# Is etcd using boltdb for it's backend?

Tags: key-value-store, etcd, boltdb

I came across on this issue on ectd [#2646](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/2646), it is quite old post but I can't find anything on the docs.

Does etcd has its own storage engine, or it is using boltdb or some other backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it appears so:

https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Gopkg.lock

```
[[projects]]
  name = "github.com/coreos/bbolt"
  packages = ["."]
  revision = "48ea1b39c25fc1bab3506fbc712ecbaa842c4d2d"
  version = "v1.3.1-coreos.6"
```

https://github.com/coreos/etcd/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bbolt&type=